# Scale FFT result frequencys in log

Tags: c#, arrays, logging, fft

I am about to program a visualizer with pretty good results. I have got an array with the size of 1500, with the magnitude of the frequencys in it. Now I want to convert this array in an array with 100 values. For example in the 1st index of the 2nd array should be the average of the first two values in the first array. On the 2nd index of the 2nd array should be the values of index 3-6. But i don't know how to calculate this properly. So how can I convert the first array into the second one?

Comment: declare the target array based on a fraction of the length of the source array, then iterate over the source array collecting your floating average (or whatever formula you intend to use) and use a division or modulo-incremented variable to determine the target index. depending on the requirements, you could also get away with sampling only every nth value, making it a loop with step > 1? show some of your existing code to get useful answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer in the [rainmeter source code.](https://github.com/rainmeter/rainmeter/blob/master/Plugins/PluginAudioLevel/PluginAudioLevel.cpp) Maybe it will now be clearer what I wanted to do here is the c# code:
To get an array with an specific length, log scaled with min. and max. frequencies.

```
private float[] getFrequencies(int min, int max, int nBands)
    {
        float[] returnVal = new float[nBands];
        double step = (Math.Log(max / min) / nBands) / Math.Log(2.0);
        returnVal[0] = (float)(min * Math.Pow(2.0, step / 2.0));

        for (int iBand = 1; iBand < nBands; ++iBand)
        {
            returnVal[iBand] = (float)(returnVal[iBand - 1] * Math.Pow(2.0, step));
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

And to fill the output array:

```
private double[] getLogArray(double[] data, int nBands, int minFreq, int maxFreq)
    {
        float[] bandFreq = getFrequencies(minFreq, maxFreq, nBands);
        float df = (float)sampleRate / samples;
        float scalar = 1.0f / sampleRate;
        double[] bandOut = new double[nBands];
        int iBin = 0;
        int iBand = 0;
        float f0 = 0.0f;

        while (iBin <= (samples / 2) && iBand < nBands)
        {
            float fLin1 = ((float)iBin + 0.5f) * df;
            float fLog1 = bandFreq[iBand];
            float x = (float)data[iBin];

            if (fLin1 <= fLog1)
            {
                bandOut[iBand] += (fLin1 - f0) * x * scalar;
                f0 = fLin1;
                iBin += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                bandOut[iBand] += (fLog1 - f0) * x * scalar;
                f0 = fLog1;
                iBand += 1;
            }
        }
        return bandOut;
    }
```

Have a nice day and sorry for the late response.